# Open OCD Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS on Windows 10 for STM32

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, cortex-m, openocd

I am trying to flash a code to a STM32F030R8T6 using Visual Studio Code and OpenOCD on Windows 10. I am also using STM32CubeMX to auto generate the beginning code and using a stlink v2. The computer can see the stlink and I can successfully connect to the STM32F030R8T6.

I am continually running into a problem where I can build the project just fine, however I can never get the flash to complete.

This is the make file that was made with STM32CubeMX and the only part I have add was the flash component.

```
##########################################################################################################################
# File automatically-generated by tool: [projectgenerator] version: [3.15.2] date: [Sun Jan 09 14:03:19 CST 2022] 
##########################################################################################################################

# ------------------------------------------------
# Generic Makefile (based on gcc)
#
# ChangeLog :
#   2017-02-10 - Several enhancements + project update mode
#   2015-07-22 - first version
# ------------------------------------------------

######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = VSCodeTest


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Core/Src/main.c \
Core/Src/stm32f0xx_it.c \
Core/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_uart_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_i2c.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_i2c_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f0xx_hal_exti.c \
Core/Src/system_stm32f0xx.c

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32f030x8.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S
 
#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m0

# fpu
# NONE for Cortex-M0/M0+/M3

# float-abi


# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32F030x8


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-ICore/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32F0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F0xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32F030R8Tx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@
    
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    
    
$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)

#######################################
# flash
#######################################
flash: all
    openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg -c "program $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf verify reset exit" 

#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

Upon doing the flash command (make flash) I run into the following error.

```
openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg -c "program build/VSCodeTest.elf verify reset exit" 
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0 (2021-11-18) [https://github.com/sysprogs/openocd]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
libusb1 09e75e98b4d9ea7909e8837b7a3f00dda4589dc3
For bug reports, read
        http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Error: libusb_open() failed with LIBUSB_ERROR_ACCESS
Error: open failed
in procedure 'program'
** OpenOCD init failed **
shutdown command invoked

make: *** [flash] Error 1
```

I have seen this solved for linux but I have not been able to find a windows.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have solved it by now. I believe this is a sequence of multiple commands. Try

```
openocd -f interface/stlink.cfg -f target/stm32f0x.cfg -c init -c "program $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf verify" -c reset -c exit
```